# How can export into an .XYZ file using decimals without scientific notation?

Tags: export, chemistry

I have seen the other posts relating to this however there seems to be more restrictions when exporting to .XYZ. I am pretty new to this but I have been searching for hours. Basically, I have a $n\times 3$ matrix:

```
matrix = {VertexTypes->{C, N, C}, 
          VertexCoordinates->{
            {-0.447094, 0.754888, -1.66937},
            {0.625759, 2.75335, -2.19647},
            {1.76312, 0.724608, -2.34303}
           }
          }
```

and after exporting it changes to scientific notation:

```
Export["hey.xyz", matrix]
```

I have tried `AccountingForm` and a few other written codes on here however also I am a beginner so I am not sure how to incorporate these into my `Export`. Secondly, I need the numbers to remain in Angstrom and not converted to picometer. If this could be prohibited I believe this would solve the problem of the introduced scientific notation which is introduced upon conversion.

Comment: there is some documentation for the XYZ format import/export. I have not studied it in detail, don't know the XYZ format and format documentation is generally rather poor, but I think you will need at least using string instead of symbols (`"VertexTypes"` vs. `VertexTypes`) and als use `"Rules"` for the element description. I would play around with the examples in the documentation (`/ref/format/XYZ` in the documentation), that usually gives you a feeling about what works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **UPDATE: an export routine written from scratch**

After clarifications from Zoe, I realize that her problem is not in the export format; not even in the sneaky way that *Mathematica* tries to outsmart the user by performing hidden unit conversions. **The problem is the output number format!**

I couldn't find a way to convince the Export function to output numbers in a format of my choosing. Fortunately, however, the [XYZ file format](http://openbabel.org/wiki/XYZ_%28format%29) is particularly simple, so I was able to cobble together **an *ad hoc* export routine**, shown below. The variables are hopefully self-explanatory.

**Function definition**

```
exportXYZ::usage = 
  "\nFunction called with incorrect parameters. Syntax is:\n exportXYZ[ filepath, { comment, vertexlist, atom coordinate list } ]";

exportXYZ::mismatch = 
  "The dimensions of the vertex list and the list of atomic coordinates do not match.";

exportXYZ[filepath_, {comment_, vertices_, atomcoordinates_}] :=
 Module[
  {outputfilestream, outputstring},

  If[
   Or[Not@StringQ[filepath], Not@StringQ[comment]],
   Message[exportXYZ::usage]; Abort[]
  ];

  If[Length@vertices != First@Dimensions@atomcoordinates,
   Message[exportXYZ::mismatch]; Abort[]
  ];

  outputstring =
   ToString@Length[vertices] <> "\n" <>
    comment <> "\n" <>
    MapThread[
     (#1 <> "\t" <> ExportString[{#2}, "TSV"] <> "\n" &),
     {vertices, atomcoordinates}
     ];

  outputfilestream = OpenWrite[filepath];
  WriteString[outputfilestream, outputstring];
  Close[outputfilestream];

  Return[outputstring]
]
```

**Using the function:**

```
(* Building blocks *)
comment = "This text will appear in the second line of the generated file";
vertices = {"C", "N", "C"};
atomcoordinates = {
   {-0.447094, 0.754888, -1.66937},
   {0.625759, 2.75335, -2.19647},
   {1.76312, 0.724608, -2.34303}
   };

exportXYZ["firstout.xyz", {comment, vertices, atomcoordinates}]

(* Out:
"3
This text will appear in the second line of the generated file
C   -0.447094   0.754888    -1.66937
N   0.625759    2.75335 -2.19647
C   1.76312 0.724608    -2.34303
"
*)
```

Hopefully this will be more helpful. A further step will be to write an export function that takes those values and neatly writes them into a file, so that it won't require manually adjusting e.g. the file path etc.

---

### Original answer:

Formatting for export is one of the most obscure sections of the documentation. What I know comes from an example in the *Mathematica* [documentation of the .XYZ file format](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XYZ.html). Look for the last bullet point under the "Elements" heading.

***Mathematica* is performing an implicit unit conversion on your input.** You can find in the documentation page that *Mathematica* interprets the values of the coordinates fed to the export function as expressed in *picometers*. On the other hand, the common [convention for the XYZ file format](http://openbabel.org/wiki/XYZ_%28format%29) is to express the coordinates in *angstrom* instead! 
Therein lies the source of the confusion: for example, your first coordinate of $-0.44$ is interpreted as -0.44 picometers (=$-0.44 \times 10^{-12}\ \textrm{m}$), translated to $-0.0044 \times 10^{-10}\ \textrm{m} = -0.0044 \ \textrm{Angstrom}$. This is why `-4.4E-3` is written to the output file.

**Export syntax:** Below is the format I use, adapted for your simple dataset, which seems to work. I have added a few comments to make the construction of the export format more clear.

```
Export[
 (* file name *)
 "hey.xyz",

 (* Data to export *)
 {
  (* List of vertices *)
  {"C", "N", "C"},

  (* List of coordinates *)
  {
    {-0.447094, 0.754888, -1.66937}, 
    {0.625759, 2.75335, -2.19647}, 
    {1.76312, 0.724608, -2.34303}
  }
 },

 (* Format specifications *)
 {"XYZ", {"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}
]
```

The contents of the exported file are shown below. The numbers and element labels are tab separated.

```
3
Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com
C   -4.47094E-3  7.54888E-3 -1.66937E-2
N    6.25759E-3  2.75335E-2 -2.19647E-2
C    1.76312E-2  7.24608E-3 -2.34303E-2
```

Comment: Yes, but the program I am running these files into cannot read the E (exp) and secondly reads in Angstrom NOT picometers. Herein lies my problem. I realise now I was not explicit enough in my question. I need full decimal form and not scientific notation.

Comment: @Zoe I see. I misunderstood. I can't think of a way of convincing Export to do that, so I wrote code to construct the output file directly from the format specifications. I haven't tested all "corner cases" though, so could you try out with some real data, if you have some at hand, and let me know how it works out for you?

Comment: This is excellent. However, I'm not sure how to use the filepath variable.
Or is that just the name of the output?

Comment: @Zoe Glad to be of help! And you are right, `filepath` is just a string in quotes that contains the name (and, if you want, the full path) of the output file you want to generate. If you don't specify a full path, MMA will typically export files to your Documents folder (check this by evaluating `$UserDocumentsDirectory` in MMA). If you do want to specify a full path, you have to escape the backslashes: for instance, if I wanted to save a file named "out.xyz" on the desktop on my Win 7 computer I would use the following string as filepath: `"C:\\Users\\Marco\\Desktop\\out.xyz"` .

Answer (score 2):

*(Updated for clarity)*

Skimming through [Developing an Export Filter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter.html) is helpful in understanding the process I describe below.

First, it is helpful to see what *Mathematica* is doing when it exports an XYZ file.  To figure this out, we can look at the appropriate formatting package:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats", "XYZ", "Export.m"}] // FilePrint
```

The package looks like this:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

ImportExport`RegisterExport[
  "XYZ",
  System`Convert`XYZDump`ExportXYZ,
  "FunctionChannels" -> {"Streams"}
]
```

If we import an example XYZ file, that sets the appropriate contexts for the export filter and we can get access to the code that is used to perform the conversion:

```
c = Import["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", {{"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates"}}];
?System`Convert`XYZDump`ExportXYZ
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Taking a closer look at this code, we note that [`PaddedForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaddedForm.html) is applied to the data:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd like to create a modified export filter that maintains the functionality of the system filter but avoids the options in `PaddedForm` that generate the scientific notation.  Perhaps the easiest way to do this is:

- Copy and paste the `Definition` text
- Rename the functions and remove reference to private contexts
- Modify the code to suit our purposes
- Register the new Export filter

The first three steps result in the code below:

```
myxyzexporter[strm_, rules_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
 Module[{elenames, atoms, coords, nobasicinput, data}, 
   ImportExport`MoleculePlot3D;
   elenames = System`ConvertersDump`Utilities`ElementNames[rules];
   If[FreeQ[elenames, "VertexTypes"] || 
     FreeQ[elenames, "VertexCoordinates"], 
    Message[Export::inselem, "XYZ"]; Return[$Failed]];
   atoms = "VertexTypes" /. rules;
   coords = "VertexCoordinates" /. rules; nobasicinput = {};
   If[Length[atoms] < 1, 
    nobasicinput = Append[nobasicinput, "VertexTypes"]];
   If[Length[coords] < 1, 
    nobasicinput = Append[nobasicinput, "VertexCoordinates"]];
   If[nobasicinput =!= {}, 
    Message[Export::nodta, nobasicinput, "XYZ"]; Return[$Failed]];
   If[Length[atoms] =!= Length[coords], 
    Message[Export::uneqlen, "VertexCoordinates", "VertexTypes"];
    Return[$Failed]];
   If[! ArrayQ[coords, 2, NumericQ] || Length[coords[[1]]] =!= 3, 
    Message[Export::errelem, "VertexCoordinates", "XYZ"];
    Return[$Failed]];
   atoms = Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`ElementNamesToNumbers[atoms];
   If[! ArrayQ[atoms, 1, IntegerQ], 
    Message[Export::badval, "VertexTypes"]; Return[$Failed]];
   data = 
    Join[{{ToString[
        Length[atoms]]}}, \
{{System`ConvertersDump`Utilities`$signature}}, 
     Partition[
      Flatten[MapThread[
        List, {Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`NumbersToElementShortNames[
          atoms], Map[ToString[
            (* THIS IS WHAT HAS CHANGED *)
            PaddedForm[#1, {7, 6}]
            (* ------------------------ *)
            ] &, coords/100.`, {2}]}]], 4]];
   data = (If[Length[#1] === 1, First[#1], 
        StringJoin @@ Riffle[#1, "\t"]] &) /@ data;
   data = StringJoin @@ Riffle[data, "\n"];
   WriteString[strm, data]] /; 
  System`ConvertersDump`Utilities`ElementsQ[rules, 
   "VertexTypes" | "VertexCoordinates"]

myxyzexporter[filename_, rules_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
 Module[{noelems}, 
  If[Head[rules] =!= List || 
    MemberQ[
     MapThread[
      Or, {(MatchQ[#1, _ :> _] &) /@ rules, (MatchQ[#1, _ -> _] &) /@ 
        rules}], False], Message[Export::type, Head[rules], "XYZ"];
   Return[$Failed], 
   noelems = 
    DeleteCases[System`ConvertersDump`Utilities`ElementNames[rules], 
     "VertexTypes" | "VertexCoordinates"];
   Message[Export::noelem, noelems, "XYZ"]; Return[$Failed]]]
```

The last step is to register the export function, which I'll call **XYZ2**

```
ImportExport`RegisterExport["XYZ2", myxyzexporter, "FunctionChannels" -> {"Streams"}]
```

Now let's fix your matrix, as it is missing some important quotation marks:

```
matrix = {"VertexTypes" -> {"C", "N", "C"}, 
  "VertexCoordinates" -> {{-0.447094, 0.754888, -1.66937}, {0.625759, 
     2.75335, -2.19647}, {1.76312, 0.724608, -2.34303}}}
```

Exporting with the new format gives us:

```
Export["fixed.xyz", matrix, "XYZ2"]
FilePrint["fixed.xyz"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

whereas the old XYZ format gives us:

```
Export["normal.xyz", matrix]
FilePrint["normal.xyz"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note**: If you need to modify the number format further, you can refer to the  [`PaddedForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PaddedForm.html) documentation and alter the portion of code that is in between the comments.

Comment: This is VERY nice! I see that you maintained the unit conversion in your export function. I have not had much opportunity to work with chemical structures in *Mathematica*, but am I correct in assuming, then, that the molecular coordinates are internally expressed in picometers? I scanned the documentation, but couldn't find a definitive answer. Would you have a pointer?

Comment: @MarcoB I've looked through a number of XYZ files and there does not appear to be a set standard, although there is a preference for Angstroms over picometers.  The [font of all web knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format) seems to have it right this time.

Comment: When trying your resolution as is, I received the error:
Export::type: "RuleDelayed cannot be exported to the \!\(\"XYZ\"\) format."

Comment: @zoe I had a typo in the `ImportExport` line (forgot the first letter when cutting and pasting).  Please try again and let me know if it works for you.